# StreamingTemplateEngine stops working after groovy code is compiled

Tags: java, groovy

I'm getting the following code to make a settings file out of a template:

```
def config_template = this.class.getResource('/config.txt.template')
def template = new groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine(config_template)
def template_data = [
  data1: [
    datadict1: this.class.getResource('file1.xml'),
    datadict2: this.class.getResource('file2.xml'),
    cert: this.class.getResource('cert1.jks'),
  ],
  data2: [
    datadict1: this.class.getResource('file3.xml'),
    datadict2: this.class.getResource('file4.xml'),
    cert: this.class.getResource('cert2.jks'),
  ]
String sessions_config_text = template.make(template_data)
File sessions_config = new File().with { f ->
  f.withWriter('UTF-8') { w ->
    w.write(sessions_config_text)
  }
  return f
}
```

That code is compiled and packaged into a jar file. When I run it I get:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine.make() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[data1:[datadict1:null, datadict2:null, cert:null, ...]]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Which makes me think `StreamingTemplateEngine.make()` will take only groovy's `Map` type, but when the code is compiled into java, `Map` is turned into a `LinkedHashMap` and `make()` method signature becomes invalid.

---

Is this right?

If so, how can I get the template engine working?

If not, what am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to create an instance of [`Template`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/text/Template.html) with [`createTemplate`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/text/StreamingTemplateEngine.html#createTemplate(java.io.Reader)) method. Then you can invoke [`make`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/text/Template.html#make(java.util.Map)) on the created template.

Comment: I realized what the issue was, it was a simple mispelling. And thank you for your answer.

Comment: @sargas so is your typo then related to the answer? future visitors of this question might be interrested in the actual solution.

Comment: @cfrick No. I called the `create_template` method rather than `createTemplate`. So no benefit to people visiting I'd assume.